# Android facebook SDK - how to do a like?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like

Does anybody know how to do a Like of a facebook page/personn by code ? Is it possible with the graph api ? how ? Can you give code example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user370003, Would you mind providing more insight? The API does not have anything for this and your "Answer" is not much help as it stands.

@Fabien, you can use a webview but the problem is if the user needs to login. you can also use:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
```

That way it will launch a web browser and you can just populate url with the string you would like to go to.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** `like` feature on Facebook Graph API.

You can find the Like Button Reference Guide on [Facebook Developers Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like).