# android facebook page like

Tags: android, android-webview

i want to like a facebook page in my android app..is there any API for this?i tried a code.it was working intially.but now it is not working

```
likeWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView1 );
likeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String url = "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?" +
       "href=" + URLEncoder.encode("likeurl" ) + "&" +
       "layout=standard&" +
       "show_faces=false&" +
       "width=500&" +
       "action=like&" +
       "colorscheme=light&" +
       "access_token=" + URLEncoder.encode( "read_stream" );
likeWebView.loadUrl( url );
```

please help me.I have been working on this for a long time.

Comment: Please have a look at this link [here][1] and [here][2]. Hope it helps you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285574/is-it-possible-to-like-a-fan-page-using-the-facebook-sdk
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076604/android-facebook-sdk-how-to-do-a-like

Comment: What does it means, `now it is not working`..? Is there any exception report in LogCat, please post it.

Comment: Use android-sdk-facebook API.

Comment: @Hadi thanks a lot.i reffered these links.but i dont want to load it using startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

Comment: @mudassir no exception is showing in logcat.but when u click the like button,login page contains sign up for experiencing this social plugin.earlier it was  showing fan page name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all u have to create facebook developer forum account. then download facebook API which ill include in your project.
You can customized the facebook API according your requirement.

This url can help you http://forum.developers.facebook.net
:)

Comment: is it possible a to like a page via facebook API?

Comment: can u provide me a sample code..i couldnot find a solution..please help me